# Why can't migrate my flutter project to androidx?

Tags: flutter, androidx

I have a flutter project I want to migrate to AndroidX. The docs say I should open Android Studio and click "Sync Project with Gradle Files" but that option is disabled for me as seen in the following picture:
[image: searching for the command from Help > Find Action]
how can I enable this option and migrate to AndroidX?

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio.

Select Open an existing Android Studio Project.

Open the android directory within your app.

Wait until the project has been synced successfully. (This happens automatically once you open the project, but if it doesn’t, select Sync Project with Gradle Files from the File menu).

If you are asked to backup the project before proceeding, check Backup project as Zip file, then click Migrate. Lastly, save the zip file in your location of preference.

The refactoring preview shows the list of changes. Finally, click Do Refactor:

That is it! You successfully migrated your project to AndroidX.

Select Migrate to AndroidX from the Refactor menu.

Comment: As I said in my question, the option to "Sync Project with Gradle Files" is disabled, and I don't know how to enable it.

Comment: Open the android directory within your app.

Comment: besides when you run your app it will sync